# best method to if/else potentially large condition

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, if-statement

Working on an MVC application.  I have hundreds of users.  Currently I'm trying to give some of our top users (maybe 10) a discount if they log-in through their assigned work-place e-mails.  The price break is shown in the Search result, Product page, Shopping Cart, and Checkout page.  I had to work on this quickly to hack it for the holiday season, so currently the way I am doing this is something like this:

ProductDetails.aspx

```
if (user == "at@at.com") {
  Product. Price * 20
}
else {
 Product.Price
}
```

As you can see, this works for now, however I'd have to do this for all 4 pages, and as our discounted users increase, this may become too long and mundane.  I'm looking at a way to go around having such a long if/else statement, and was wondering if it makes sense to use a stored procedure instead or a method?

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest to add a discount field to the user table or any appropriate table in the database and save the discount info there. You can also create a new table that holds the discount information tied up to the different users and manage to return the discount value instead of going through an if/else statement.

Comment: Or at least an `IDictionary` of some kind.